# cannot pass deleted lambda function with move?

Tags: c++, lambda, move-semantics

I have the following lambda expression:

```
    auto pPerson = std::make_unique<Person>("Person");
    
    auto personLambda = [=, persPointer = std::move(pPerson)](int x, int y) mutable
    {
        //do stuff
    };

    acceptLambda(myVector, personLambda);//compiler error
```

acceptLambda():

```
template<typename Func>
void acceptLambda(std::vector<int> myVector, Func f) {
//do stuff
}
```

error:

```
function "lambda []std::string (int c, int y) mutable->std::string<unnamed>(const lambda []std::string (int x, int y) mutable->std::string &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

As outlined above, I am running into a compiler error telling me I cannot pass this lambda into the acceptLamba() function. I have other lambdas above that work just fine; when I pass personLambda in (which contains an std::move in the capture clause) everything breaks.

When I remove the move operation on the unique_ptr, everything works as expected. However, I want to move this unique_ptr into the lambda for use in a concurrent environment and avoid a dangling pointer situation.

Why does the `std::move` operation cause this error? How does one remedy this issue?

Comment: For some reason visual studio won't let me copy & paste from the text box, so I just took a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Two things to think about: why did you have to move (not copy) the `unique_ptr` into the lambda? When you pass the lambda as a parameter, does the lambda (and its captured variables) get copied?

Comment: @JaMiT I'm very new to c++ (spent a long time in java). From what I understand, copying a unique_ptr is dangerous, as once this ptr is out of scope, its destructor is called. If there are copied pointers at this now deleted memory, we can have problems.

Comment: @Matthew Not quite. Give it a try. Right after `auto pPerson = std::make_unique<Person>("Person");` try to make a copy of it with a line like `std::unique_ptr<Person> copy = pPerson;`. What happens?

Comment: You can make `acceptLambda` to take `Func` by reference, or move closure to that function by `std::move`: `acceptLambda(myVector, std::move(personLambda));`.

Comment: Hmm... no luck finding a suitable duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a the error message:

> `function "lambda []std::string (int c, int y) mutable->std::string<unnamed>(const lambda []std::string (int x, int y) mutable->std::string &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

That's a mouthful. It's more understandable if you recognize that `lambda []std::string (int c, int y) mutable->std::string` is a name for the type of your lambda (apparently its `return` statement causes the `auto` to be deduced as `std::string`). Let's call that type `L` and see what the message looks like.

> `function "L(const L &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

Your lambda's copy constructor is implicitly deleted. That should make sense since your lambda has captured a non-copyable value (the `unique_ptr`). And yet, you try to make a copy when you pass `personLambda` **by value** to `acceptLambda`. This does not work.

*The full error message probably has more information that could help point you to seeing why your lambda cannot be copied. After the `error` line are probably some `note` lines explaining that `unique_ptr` cannot be copied. When using an IDE, such as Visual Studio, you might have to switch from the summary compiler output tab to the full compiler output tab to see this, though.*

**Option 1**
You might be able to pass the lambda **by reference**. Might. Maybe you do need a copy in the larger scheme of things, but if you don't, then `acceptLambda` could take its second argument by reference (and probably should take the first argument by const reference).

```
void acceptLambda(const std::vector<int> & myVector, Func & f) 
//                                                        ^-- by reference
```

**Option 2**
You could get around being unable to copy your lambda the same way you got around being unable to copy your `unique_ptr`. You could move it. Just be aware that `personLambda` will not be usable after the call to `acceptLambda`. (If this is a problem, you likely should be using a `shared_ptr` instead of a `unique_ptr`.)

```
acceptLambda(myVector, std::move(personLambda));
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^            ^
```